# Deltaspike 0.7, Primefaces 5.0, tomee 1.6.0 and NPE

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, apache-tomee, deltaspike

I have a quite large web project which has been running fine with deltaspike 0.5 and the os890 @viewaccesscoped implementation.

Now, I've been trying to upgrade to DS 0.7 but have met quite a challenge.
I've tried to reproduce the error in another project but I'm not been able to get the NPE.

anyway, I was just wondering if someone has seen anything similar or could give me a hint where to start debugging:

The stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
org.apache.deltaspike.jsf.impl.injection.AbstractBeanStorage.add(AbstractBeanStorage.java:35)
org.apache.deltaspike.jsf.impl.injection.RequestDependentBeanStorage.add(RequestDependentBeanStorage.java:24)
org.apache.deltaspike.jsf.impl.injection.ManagedArtifactResolver.getContextualReference(ManagedArtifactResolver.java:87)
org.apache.deltaspike.jsf.impl.injection.ManagedArtifactResolver.resolveManagedConverter(ManagedArtifactResolver.java:53)
org.apache.deltaspike.jsf.impl.injection.InjectionAwareApplicationWrapper.managedOrDefaultConverter(InjectionAwareApplicationWrapper.java:74)
org.apache.deltaspike.jsf.impl.injection.InjectionAwareApplicationWrapper.createConverter(InjectionAwareApplicationWrapper.java:54)
org.primefaces.config.ConfigContainer.initConfig(ConfigContainer.java:100)
org.primefaces.config.ConfigContainer.<init>(ConfigContainer.java:82)
org.primefaces.context.DefaultApplicationContext.<init>(DefaultApplicationContext.java:35)
org.primefaces.context.DefaultRequestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultRequestContext.java:227)
org.primefaces.metadata.ComponentMetadataTransformerListener.processEvent(ComponentMetadataTransformerListener.java:40)
javax.faces.event.SystemEvent.processListener(SystemEvent.java:43)
org.apache.myfaces.application.ApplicationImpl._traverseListenerList(ApplicationImpl.java:2493)
org.apache.myfaces.application.ApplicationImpl.access$000(ApplicationImpl.java:120)
org.apache.myfaces.application.ApplicationImpl$SystemListenerEntry.publish(ApplicationImpl.java:2684)
org.apache.myfaces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(ApplicationImpl.java:601)
org.apache.myfaces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(ApplicationImpl.java:616)
javax.faces.application.ApplicationWrapper.publishEvent(ApplicationWrapper.java:336)
javax.faces.application.ApplicationWrapper.publishEvent(ApplicationWrapper.java:336)
org.apache.deltaspike.jsf.impl.injection.InjectionAwareApplicationWrapper.publishEvent(InjectionAwareApplicationWrapper.java:121)
org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RestoreViewExecutor.execute(RestoreViewExecutor.java:283)
org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:170)
org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:117)
org.apache.deltaspike.jsf.impl.listener.request.DeltaSpikeLifecycleWrapper.execute(DeltaSpikeLifecycleWrapper.java:89)
javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:197)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Best regards,
hw

Comment: After writing this, I found out that its due to a @FacesConverter(forClass=String.class).....

Comment: I just saw that the same question is on the mailing list. Their answer is: With TomEE 1.7+ it should work and before that you can deactivate this feature. And if you upgrade to the latest version, you will find the scope you are using in DeltaSpike directly.